# ASP.NET webapi messed up when url contains @ character

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, restful-url

In our restful api some calls contains an email in the url, like this:
http://api2.uat.allpointsportal.com/consumers/eee@ggg.com/

In this case the call succeeds, but if I remove the end slash, the call answers with a 404, it seems like the routing mechanism is messed up when the latest parameter in the url contains a @ character.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: UrlEncode should do it.

Comment: The fact is that it does not need the encoding if the slash is at the end, it seems to me like a bug in the parsing or routing in .net.

Comment: Now it also happens with periods, I tried encoding the url, but still the only way is by adding the slash.